# Loading an image returns 404 initially

Tags: angular, types, angular5

I am getting a 404 error logged to the console, when I try to retrieve an image.

> GET http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found)

The code:

```
 <img [src]="user && user.profileUrl" width="150" height="150" class="rounded" alt="pic">
```

In the above code `user.profileUrl` is a url that will be something like `https://example.com/imag.png`. I think it takes too much time to load the image and until that happens it returns a `404 error`. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Why are you setting `user` to `[src]`?. Is `user` an image source? `4 && 5` will return `5`. Same way if `user` is `true`, it will be set to `[src]` and if it's not an image source, it will return an error

Answer (score 0):

remove the additional condition and use `?`

```
[src]="user?.profileUrl"
```

Comment: i still keep getting it

Comment: try <img *ngIf="user?.profileUrl" [src]="user.profileUrl"> or <img [src]="user.profileUrl || null">